# How to use webBrowser1_Navigated method inside timer tick method C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

how would I use this code

```
         private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
                {
 if (Convert.ToInt32(myhour) == hours && Convert.ToInt32(myminutes) == minutes) {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate("www.remaxit.com/members"); // way before this
    deleted = true;
    HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
    doc.GetElementById("AddUser").InvokeMember("CLICK"); //This executes
                }
               }
```

inside this

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Time is ticking");
        }
```

So what I am trying to do is when the current time matches the time i want, it will click a button. If I don't use the navigated method the page doesn't fully load and a null exception is thrown. That is why I am using the navigated method but how can I use the navigated method with a timer so that when the time matches my web browser navigates to www.remaxit.com/members.

Comment: Call the Navigate() method in your Tick event handler.  Set a bool variable so you know it was the timer that forced the navigation and no other Navigate() should be accepted.  Use the DocumentCompleted event and that variable to do the clicking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this way should work for you:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickAtTime();
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    ClickAtTime();
}

private void ClickAtTime() 
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(myhour) == hours && Convert.ToInt32(myminutes) == minutes) 
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.remaxit.com/members"); // way before this
        deleted = true;
        HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("AddUser").InvokeMember("CLICK"); //This executes
    }
}
```

Put the functionality that you want to repeat into its own method and call it from both places.